# C# Regex locate groups missing a string?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, locate

First off, I am HORRIBLE with Regex.  Apologies up front if this is dead easy and I'm just missing it :(

Ok, so let's say I'm looking to parse my source code, and find all of my private functions.  Further, let's say I want to get that entire block of code so I can examine it.

Regex match of:

```
Private Function[\s\S]*?End Function
```

works great.

Now, what if I want to find all functions that are missing a Return statement?  I can not seem to figure this one out (see above re: regex and I don't get along famously).

Anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?  I'm using .NET implementation of regex if that matters (and it seems to - none of the Java examples I find seem to work!)

I'm using regexstorm.net for my testing, if it matters :)  Thanks!

Comment: why dont you just use your above regex, then foreach match, check if the captured string contains `return`?  That'll be pretty accurate and pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be analyzing Visual Basic.  You could use Microsoft's Code Analysis tools ([Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)) in order parse the code and analyze the different parts.  This will prevent having to look for varying syntax acceptance of different code files.  The following sample code will determine if a `Function` is private or has an as clause.

```
string code = @"
    Function MyFunction()
    End Function

    Private Function MyPrivateFunction()
    End Function

    Function WithAsClause() As Integer
    End Function
    ";

// Parse the code file.
var tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

var root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();

// Find all functions in the code file.
var nodes = root.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(n => n.Kind() == SyntaxKind.FunctionBlock)
    .Cast<MethodBlockSyntax>();

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    // Analyze the data for the function.
    var functionName = node.SubOrFunctionStatement.Identifier.GetIdentifierText();
    bool isPrivate = node.BlockStatement.Modifiers.Any(m => m.Kind() == SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword);
    var asClause = node.SubOrFunctionStatement.AsClause;
    bool hasAsClause = asClause != null;

    Console.WriteLine($"{functionName}\t{isPrivate}\t{hasAsClause}");
}
```

Comment: Ok... that.. is friggin' cool, I won't lie.  Thanks, I had no idea this even existed!!

Comment: Depending upon what your project requirements are you can also automate updating the code too with the same framework.